# Spark Structured Streaming Kafka Integration - Streaming Query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm working on an application that would connect to a Kafka source and on the same source, I would want to create multiple streaming queries with different filter conditions. Each of the queries would be processing a business logic and writing it to HBase.

I'm trying to solve some race conditions in the business logic, and want to understand how the internals of Spark Strucutured Streaming work while reading from Kafka.

1) How many Kafka consumers would be created across the application? Would it be related to the number of partitions on the topic or to the number of executors running the application?

2) Would each of the streaming query write to the same unbounded table with 1 Kafka consumer per query?